# How do you determin a parent/child relationship in Intersystems Cache?

Tags: join, implicit, intersystems-cache

I'm having trouble using implicit joins or Arrow joins "->". It's on an Intersystems Cache database. This is my code that isn't working

> SELECT qcpr_arf_OC.AssessmentCategoryDataElement->AssessmentCategoryID 
>   FROM qcpr_arf_OC.AssessmentCategory

I've read through Intersystems Implicit join page http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20102/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GSQL_specialfeatures

And I tried to alter this one to work as it's also a for the QCPR application [Intersystems Cache coding query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114280/intersystems-cache-coding-query)

So am I doing something wrong or am I assuming a parent/child relationship when there is none? If so how do I tell? Thank you to everyone for your time.

Comment: what table are you actually querying? I ask because `qcpr_arf_OC.AssessmentCategoryDataElement` is a full table reference which is different from the `qcpr_arf_OC.AssessmentCategory` table in your FROM clause. Are you trying to get data/values from `qcpr_arf_OC.AssessmentCategoryDataElement` rows that are related to a specific `qcpr_arf_OC.AssessmentCategory`? If so, your query may need to look something like:
`SELECT AssessmentCategoryID FROM qcpr_arf_OC.AssessmentCategoryDataElement WHERE AssessmentCategoryID = '1234'`

Could you describe the information you want?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get data from "AssessmentCategoryDataElement" using the implicit join on the "AssessmentCategory" table. I just wrote this in the hopes I could get it working for practice. I'm just trying to understand how this works. I think this would be a powerful tool to understand and instead of me looking up the columns that match every time I want to join a column from another table I could just write -> and not worry. The reason I put a full table reference is because of this example 

SELECT Name AS EmpName, Company->Name AS CompName
FROM Sample.Employee

Comment: I got it :)
SELECT ID, LastEditEmployeeID->Initials
FROM qcpr_arf_OC.AssessmentCategory

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you are using is correct, but without database schema it's difficult to find an actual error.

What I would suggest, is to use "Query Builder" to create your first few queries in Cache. It's accessible from Management Protal -> Explore -> SQL, "Execute Query" tab, and there is a "Query Builder" button above text area. Don't forget to switch to your application namespace.

Comment: I understand now! Thank you. I tested this and it works.
SELECT ID, LastEditEmployeeID->Initials
FROM qcpr_arf_OC.AssessmentCategory